# Short Movie: Time Travel In A Bathtub Or In Just Water

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

Within the last 4-5 years, I enjoyed a short movie, probably from SIFF because it was on an Alaska Airlines flight. It was about a man (Caucasian, probably in his 20's) who discovered or happened on how to either teleport or time travel in his bathtub. If he got under the water, and maybe did something, but I forget what, he'd teleport or time travel. As the movie progressed, he did stranger and stranger things with this ability, one of which was to teleport with only a part of his body under the water, a situation that ended up with his body severed at the waterline. But he was okay after that and the movie continued. I think that when he did this, the water would disappear from the tub.

<sub>This isn't *Hot Tub Time Machine*.</sub>

Comment: "I am NOT referring to "Hot Tub Time Machine"."; That's a shame!

Comment: Probably not what you're searching for but "The Butterfly Effect 3: Revelations" featured some time travel while submerged in a bathtub. Perhaps someone else coming across this question is looking for that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long shot and not a complete match with your description, but then again some details do line up. Was it [Hirsute](https://vimeo.com/2381662)?

Synopsis:

> A young physicist is visited by an arrogant, time-traveling, future version of himself. Shocked to discover his fondness for body-hair removal and boiled eggs, the young physicist vows to change the course of his life.
>
> From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1077348/)

Trailer

Comment: When answering an answer, try to give as much info as possible, like synopsis, description and similar in order for the asker to be able to determine if it's correct. Also, the link you've provided might be deleted.

Comment: Awesome! Yes, that was it. Hirsute. Thanks very much!

Comment: Ah, nice, glad I could help! And thanks for the heads up @Shade, I'll keep that in mind going forward,